# Generating a new variable using conditional statements

Tags: stata

Given the following dataset and commands:

```
sysuse auto, clear

generate x = .
replace x = 5 if price == 4099
replace x = 5 if price == 4749
```

I want to generate a new variable `x` that is equal to `5` if `price` belongs to a list of values.

The following command generates no new values of `x` and is incorrect:

```
replace x = 5 if price == 4099 & price == 4749
```

I need a simpler one-line method that does not involve replacing `x` the way I did it in the code above, which works, but is tedious and inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'or' (`|`) instead of 'and' (`&`):

```
sysuse auto, clear

generate x = .
replace x = 5 if price == 4099
replace x = 5 if price == 4749

generate y = 5 if price == 4099 | price == 4749
```

Alternatively you can use the `inlist()` function:

```
generate z = 5 if inlist(price, 4099, 4749)
```

Results:

```
list price x y z in 1 / 5

     +-------------------+
     | price   x   y   z |
     |-------------------|
  1. | 4,099   5   5   5 |
  2. | 4,749   5   5   5 |
  3. | 3,799   .   .   . |
  4. | 4,816   .   .   . |
  5. | 7,827   .   .   . |
     +-------------------+
```